# Highcharts combination

Tags: highcharts

I would like to ask about chart combination in Highcharts.

Is there any possible combine the multiple axis chart which is located in Highcharts with the Highstock scroll bar features ?

thank you for reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can use highstock.js with combine with Highcharts. Then `scrollbar` will be avaiable. Please take look at example:

http://jsfiddle.net/anm6z/1/

Comment: thx for your sample.
sorry for my mistaken. the scroll bar is the highstock range selector feature which mean I want display a graph which is combine the multiple axis chart which is located in Highcharts with the Highstock range selector feature which are YTD and etc

Comment: so add rangeselector { enabled:true }

Comment: hi thank for your reply again. But it seem like did not work correctly. =.=ll

Comment: That is very nice example but i am here with question instead of showing data for rainfall in decimal points that is possible to show data in rainfall with minutes ?

Comment: You should use timestamps (time in miliseocnds) for your data points and adapt axes by [tickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.tickInterval)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about scroll bar but there is a example called [master-detail](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail) check it out once. it may be helpful to you

Comment: hi, sorry for my mistaken. the scroll bar is the highstock range selector feature which mean I want display a graph which is combine the multiple axis chart which is located in Highcharts with the Highstock range selector feature which are YTD and etc.